# Sync erp with opencart

Tags: synchronization, opencart, erp

I have an Erp software which uses mssql 2012 database. 
I also use opencart for my ecommerce solution. As you already know opencart uses mysql database.

I want to bidirectional sync the erp with opencart.

Erp will send categories, products, product options, stock to opencart 
And opencart will send orders to the erp.

I know the schema on both systems so I know which tables must be updated.

The question is
What is the best method to sync two different databases?
Especially when these two databases are different (mssql-mysql) and the schemas are completely different **and also mssql is local but mysql can be accessed only remotely from the web server**.

I searched and found the below options 
-Connect the mysql database as external to the sql management studio and run queries from one database to the other through sql agent.
-Use of SSIS?
-PHP? But I have little knowledge.
-C sharp application?
-Third party software like symmetricsds?

Please tell me your opinion. 
Thank you

Comment: My Solution for this case is SQL Server OPENQUERY. Create openquery connection to MySQL (must open port 3306). Create queries to update stock, price values, order status etc. The best way is with API but your business software must support this and is more difficult. [tag:erp] [tag:opencart]

Answer (score 0):

A scheduled script or a cron job  in any language , which will run periodically and do following

1. Export data from MSSQL to MySQl.

   2. Import data from MySQl to MSSQL.

If you need details then let me know.

This can be done easily with PHP

Answer (score 0):

I have been developing a similar concept, currently I have it setup with `CSV` files. This way the link is more secure. So the external system generated `CSV files` periodically and then uploads it to an `FTP` on the website. Once there the website looks and sees if there is files in there and then `runs a script` to update the information on the website. This works both ways, so new orders generate a similar `CSV` script which is then imported into the external program to deal with and send back a result.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is that the above project can be accomplished with many methods. Php, c sharp, scv, sql queries and so on.

The biggest challenge I believe is the different schemas. For example the erp stores products in 5 tables but opencart in 4. Also opencart has a simple auto increment id for every entity but the erp has a more complex guid. So, no easy mapping. 
I know I can use the sku field at opencart to setup the mapping but what about categories?